# Conflicting Gesture Recognizers on UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have two custom controls on my `UIView`, the one is the now popular sliding menu (when you slide the finger on the `NavBar` the view slides to the right) and the other one is on the `UITableViewCell` - it's a custom `TableViewCell` from the control named **DMSlidingTableViewCell** (Like in **Twitter** app - when you slide the cell on the left, it reveals some buttons, etc.)

They work just fine, but when I try to add a Gesture recognizer to the whole UITableView thus making the whole view a region for `UIGestureRecognizer` (so when I move it I can move the view to the right) the gestures recognizers somehow conflict.

What can be the reason here?

Comment: what gestures are you trying to recognize on the table cell and on the table as a whole? is it the same kind? different?

Comment: @sergio The gesture recognizers are both of SwipeGesture, but with or without the same direction, they just don't work.

Comment: check http://www.chewyapps.com/2012/10/26/swiping-on-a-uitableviewcell/ and http://kaihangjia.blog.163.com/blog/static/2145761562012111224644877/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not clear about the way you think that two swipe gesture recognizers could work together in that context, but I think you could try and give a look at the

```
– gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:
```

[delegate method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate/gestureRecognizer%3ashouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer%3a).

Keep in mind that you have 2 gestures, so 2 delegate (conceptually, they be implemented by the same method), so you could make one gesture (first argument) always return NO, the other YES and see if you can make the 2 gesture recognizers work together in a satisfactorily way.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {

    if ([gestureRecognizer.view isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]]) {
       ...
    } else {
       ...
    }
}
```

This is just an example which should work in your case (check the syntax, though), but you could also store the 2 recognizers in properties of your class, so you know which one is which.

Comment: And I wonder, how do you specify which gesture recognizer should respond to which method in a single class?

Answer (score 5):

When I use UIGestureRecognizer on a UITableView, I met the same problem  like u.Finally, I found the "cancelsTouchesInView" property in UIGestureRecognizer by this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12851794),and its helpful.

```
  UIGestureRecognizer* tapGesture = [[UIGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
  **tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;**//pass touch event to others
```

best wishes！