# Gestures Conflict on UITableView swipe to delete iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a problem in my gesture recognizers. My goal is to implement using swipe to delete in my table view. But I think other gestures are conflicting with each other. I'm using this libray [romaonthego/REFrostedViewController](https://github.com/romaonthego/REFrostedViewController)
 this a library for my hamburger menu and this library has a pangesture feature. I think the conflict is w/in the gestures. because when I run my code of my tableview in another project it's working.Pls help, Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think… you must disable "panGestureEnabled” and present the “menu" manually [self.frostedViewController presentMenuViewController];

Comment: But I also need the pan gesture. I disabled the pan gesture but It's not working at all. I saw some applications used pan gestures on there menu and gesture to delete tha data in a table. I want to know how did they managed two run 2 pan gestures. T_T

Comment: but.. what conflict do you have? You can't present the menu… or you can’t swipe the cell?

Comment: I can't swipe the cell.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem, what I ended up doing is similar to TonyMkenu , but there are more recognizers that you need to allow:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {

if (otherGestureRecognizer.delegate == self )
    return NO;

//if otherGestureRecognizer is swipe to delete from a UITableView cancel slide menu recognizers

if ([[otherGestureRecognizer.view class] isSubclassOfClass:[UITableView class]])
{
    NSLog(@"Allow1 %@", [otherGestureRecognizer description]);

    return YES;
}

if( [[otherGestureRecognizer.view class] isSubclassOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]] ||
[NSStringFromClass([otherGestureRecognizer.view class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellScrollView"] ||
[NSStringFromClass([otherGestureRecognizer.view class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewWrapperView"])
{
    NSLog(@"Allow&Disable %@", [otherGestureRecognizer description]);

    if(gestureRecognizer.delegate == self)
    {//cancel the slide menu recognizer

        gestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
        gestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
    }

    return YES;
}

NSLog(@"Deny %@", [otherGestureRecognizer description]);
return NO;
```

}

Answer (score 4):

**Edit: Updated for iOS 11**

The other answers were helpful, but in my case the best solution was to do the logic in `shouldRequireFailureOfOtherGesture` like so:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    if (gestureRecognizer == self.pan) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    if (gestureRecognizer == self.pan) {

        // iOS 10
        if ([NSStringFromClass([otherGestureRecognizer.view class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewWrapperView"]) {
            return YES;
        }
        // iOS 11
        else if ([otherGestureRecognizer isMemberOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]] && [otherGestureRecognizer.view isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]]) {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

This had a much better behavior in my case. I also used `delaysTouchesBegan = YES` on my pan gesture. Might be useful!

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 11，hope this can help you.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    if ([[otherGestureRecognizer.view class] isSubclassOfClass:[UITableView class]]) {
        if ([otherGestureRecognizer isKindOfClass: [UIPanGestureRecognizer class]]) {
            UIPanGestureRecognizer *otherPan = (UIPanGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer;
            CGPoint translation = [otherPan translationInView:otherGestureRecognizer.view];
            return translation.x < 0;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all... check if you have this

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
```

and second...

try to add this

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {

    if ([gestureRecognizer.view isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]]) {
       return YES;
    } else {
       return NO;
    }
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14338043

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I already solve my problem by putting a reference to the gesture of my hamburger menu. Thank you for your answer :)