# Two Gestures getting recognized simultaneously

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uipangesturerecognizer, collectionview

I have two collectionview positioned one below the another, something similar to Skype Like Navigation (kindly check the latest Skype iPhone App). The Complete structure has been working fine along with the parallax scrolling of the header view. Check it at [Skype Like Navigation Github](https://github.com/shwetsolanki/SkypeLikeNavigation)

In the app if you see, when you scroll the Content CollectionView, the top header view also scrolls depending on the header cell size. And when the Header CollectionView is scrolled, the Content CollectionView also scrolls.

I have written all the calculation for the Content Collection View scrolled by user, and in order to get the desired working when the user scrolls the Header Collection View, I have added the Pan Gesture of ContentCollectionView to the Header Collection View and it just worked fine.

But there is a side effect to it, my Content Collection Cell contains a UITableView, now when I try to scroll the tableview and if my finger moves slight right or left, the Content Collection View also scrolls (FYI, UITableView is vertical scrolling and UICollectionView is Horizontal Scrolling).

I believe adding the Pan Gesture to Header CollectionView has messed up the scrolling.

So if anyone knows the fix, do let me know.

Demo : [Skype Like Navigation Demo](https://github.com/shwetsolanki/SkypeLikeNavigation)

Thanks

Comment: Use something like the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14337753/conflicting-gesture-recognizers-on-uitableview?rq=1

Comment: That is not helpful. Check the Demo, you will get an idea, what issue I am exactly facing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have it now. The simple gist of it is, that you disable scrolling on your collectionviews when the table view scrolls.

For further information please see [my pull request](https://github.com/shwetsolanki/SkypeLikeNavigation/pull/1) on Github.

Comment: Could you please accept my answer so other people see this solved the question?