# UItapgesture not working with uitableview

Tags: iphone, xcode

Here's my code:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(resignTextView)];
    [self.tableview addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];


-(void)resignTextView
{
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
}
```

I added tableview with `UITapGetureRecognizer`. I do not know why it is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please add

```
 gestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = numberOfTapsRequired;
```

where `numberOfTapsRequired` is an int and than try. (be default it is 1, you can try it with 2 to check)

and since you are using UITableView I am not sure what type of hierarchy you are dealing with... you can have a look at this answer to understand how this works..

[UITapGestureRecognizer breaks UITableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192480/uitapgesturerecognizer-breaks-uitableview-didselectrowatindexpath)

Comment: thanx.it is working.How do i resign keyboard when user scrolldown the tableView?.