# Table view not accessible when using tap gesture

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I am using a tap gesture on my view which also has a table view as a subview. The table does scroll but when tapped, instead of calling `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` it calls the selector associated with the tap gesture. I can detect the tapped view by getting tap location.
    I want to access `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` when tapped on table instead of the tap gesture selector. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Check

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192480/uitapgesturerecognizer-breaks-uitableview-didselectrowatindexpath

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement the tap gesture's UIGestureRecognizerDelegate , and prevent the gesture if touch is in the tableview.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:view] ;
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(tableview.frame, p)) {
        return NO ;
    }
    return YES ;
}
```