# Gesture Recognizer Not Called

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I have set up a gesture recognizer for dismissing the keyboard when the user taps outside the textfield. `DismissKeyboard` function does not get called.

Have I set up the observer wrong or is this a different issue? Also, this is a tableview that is being tapped.

#### Code Excerpt

```
class CommentsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
            selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"),
            name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification,
            object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
            selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"),
            name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification,
            object: nil)
    }

    func keyboardFrameChanged(notification: NSNotification) {
        println("keyboardFrameChanged")
        let userInfo = notification.userInfo
        let key = UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey
        if let info = userInfo {
            let frameValue = info[key] as! NSValue
            let _frame = frameValue.CGRectValue()
        }
    }
    
    func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        if keyboardDismissTapGesture == nil
        {
            println("dismiss")
            keyboardDismissTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("dismissKeyboard:"))
            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(keyboardDismissTapGesture!)
        }
    }
    
    func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        if keyboardDismissTapGesture != nil
        {
            println("test2")
            self.view.removeGestureRecognizer(keyboardDismissTapGesture!)
            keyboardDismissTapGesture = nil
        }
    }
    
    func dismissKeyboard(sender: AnyObject) {
        println("dismiss keyboard")
        commentTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
```

I set a breakpoint at dismissKeyboard, but it doesn't even get called.

#### Output

When I tap the textview and the keyboard opens, this is the output

```
keyboardFrameChanged
keyboardFrameChanged
will show
dismiss
```

When I tap anything else (trying to dismiss the keyboard), no further outputs.

Comment: Are the notifications for the keyboard showing and hiding being called?

Comment: Instead of Breakpoints I would consider placing some `println()` statements and then see how far it gets. Can you do that for us?

Comment: @chedabob yes keyboardWillShow is getting called.

Comment: @LinusG. sure, but i already have println statements in each of the functions. where else should I add them?

Comment: True but they are pretty useless for us if you don't show the output ;)

Comment: @LinusG. you're right! I updated the question :)

Comment: When you tap on table view is the keyboard getting dismissed?

Comment: @Krish not it is not. `println("dismiss keyboard")` is not even being called.

Comment: Thanks. So either I am blind or you just don't show it. How do you create your `UIGestureRecognizer`? And to which view do you add it?

Comment: @LinusG. I did not have it shown. I didn't want to make the question too long so I pasted the entire viewcontroller here: http://pastebin.com/mxgiPad0

Comment: try adding gesture recognizer to the table view instead of view.

Comment: @Krish just tried `self.tableView.addGestureRecognizer(keyboardDismissTapGesture!)` still not calling `dismissKeyboard`

Comment: try moving the gesture recognizer portion to viewDidAppear method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the gesture recognizer delegate to yourself and add the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol.

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if keyboardDismissTapGesture == nil
    {
        println("dismiss")
        keyboardDismissTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: view, action: "dismissKeyboard:")
        keyboardDismissTapGesture.delegate = self
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(keyboardDismissTapGesture!)
    }
}
```

Then add:

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool { 
    return true 
}
```

My guess is, the gesture of your table view is interfering with the new `UITapGesture`. Try this solution or else you should fail the gesture of your table view when your new `UITapGesture` is detected.

To fail the `UITapGestureRecognizer` of the table view I use this code:

```
if let recognizers = yourTableView.gestureRecognizers, let index = find(recognizers.map { $0 is UITapGestureRecognizer }, true) {
    (recognizers[index] as! UIPanGestureRecognizer).requireGestureRecognizerToFail(keyboardDismissTapGesture)
}
```

Maybe not the most elegant way of doing it, but it works for me when I want to fail the **`UIPanGestureRecognizer`**. I haven't tested it with the `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

EDIT:

```
if let recognizers = yourTableView.gestureRecognizers, let index = find(recognizers.map { $0 is UIGestureRecognizer }, true) {
    (recognizers[index] as! UIGestureRecognizer).requireGestureRecognizerToFail(keyboardDismissTapGesture!)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! `println("dismiss keyboard")` is now being called but only when I drag + tap immediately after. Is there a reason why the gesture is not recognizing individual taps?

Comment: The default for iOS is that it can only recognize one gesture at a time. I'm not that experienced yet so I can only tell you this. Something else you can do is to fail the tap gesture of the table view. I'll show you how in a sec. And if this solved your problem, please mark it as answered :p

Comment: Thank you. Would you mind explaining what failing the gesture does?

Comment: Lol, i mean why do I want to fail it?

Comment: Sorry, I just woke up. It means, gesture1 stops working when the gesture2 is detected. This is useful like when you want to pan a view up or down and your view has a table view. Normally, if you pan vertically, you will pan your table. If this is failed, you can successfully use gesture2.

Comment: If you're going to use the "fail" option, please let me know if it works. Kinda lazy to test it myself right now :p And you're welcome.

Comment: I put it in `func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {`, but nothing different happened. And `keyboardDismissTapGesture` should have `!`

Comment: I've put an edit in the answer. You can try that. I hope it succeeds. If it doesn't you'll have to use the gesture delegate like in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192480/uitapgesturerecognizer-breaks-uitableview-didselectrowatindexpath).

Comment: I added the new code. It crashes when I try to tap the textView `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFSet addObject:]: attempt to insert nil'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77852/discussion-between-jacobson-talom-and-emma).