# Keyboard Covers TextField (multiple textfields)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have 3 textfields, but the keyboard covers the textfield when it pops up on each of them. How can I move the textfield up each time the keyboard pops up?

#### Current Attempt:

The current attempt with the code below gets called, but does not change the layout at all (followed a different StackOverflow answer).

#### Code Excerpt:

```
class UploadPhotoViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var photoTitleTextField: UITextField! // title textfield
    @IBOutlet var photoCommentTextField: UITextField! 
    @IBOutlet var photoPriceTextField: UITextField!


    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)


        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
            selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"),
            name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification,
            object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
            selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"),
            name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification,
            object: nil)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)

        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.photoTitleTextField.delegate = self;
        self.photoCommentTextField.delegate = self;
        self.photoPriceTextField.delegate = self;

        }
    }

    func goBack()
    {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        self.view.endEditing(true);
        return false;
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        self.view.endEditing(true);
    }

    func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

        println("will show")

        var info = notification.userInfo!
        var keyboardFrame: CGRect = (info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.bottomConstraint.constant = keyboardFrame.size.height + 20
        })


    }

    func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        println("will hide")

    }

}
```

#### This is what the UIViewController looks like:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Move a view up only when the keyboard covers an input field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28813339/move-a-view-up-only-when-the-keyboard-covers-an-input-field)

Comment: both textfield hiding ?

Comment: @nerkyator can you explain how to apply the answer to multiple textfields?

Comment: @AshishKakkad yes, each one is being covered when the keyboard pops up

Comment: With `activeField` variable. on `textFieldDidBeginEditing` you assign current editing textfield, so when `keyboardWasShown` fires it will scroll the scrollview and keyboard will not cover it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IQKeyboardManager in your project from [here](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager).

> To use IQKeyboardManager you simply need to add source files to your project.

**Key Features**

1. **CODELESS**, Zero Line Of Code
2. Works Automatically
3. No More UIScrollView
4. No More Subclasses
5. No More Manual Work
6. No More #imports

Try it!

Comment: I will give it a try. But I had some issues with third party libs (tried 1-2 already).

Comment: @Emma, but this will not make any difference, you just have to drag & drop the files in your project nothing else. If still facing any issue, do tell me.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @bgilham: Thanks for pointing it out! Will remember it in future. :)

Comment: @RajatDeepSingh Hi, i just gave this a try today. But after adding the files to my project, the textfields are still exactly the same (covered by keyboard).

Comment: Can you tell me what files you have added?

Comment: @RajatDeepSingh actually i was able to get it to work by adding this to the appdelegate `IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true`. But there seem to be conflicts with one of my other viewcontrollers that has a bottom bar textfield. Is it possible to disable the IQKeyboardManager on certain viewControllers (swift)?

Comment: @RajatDeepSingh even when I set `IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().disableInViewControllerClass(CommentsViewController)` there are still conflicts with my other viewController see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30247506/gesture-recognizer-not-called

Comment: @RajatDeepSingh how can I disable it completely in certain viewcontrollers?

Comment: You want to use it in only some view Controllers?

Comment: You want to use this functionality in VC1 and not in VC2, you are saying this only?

Comment: @RajatDeepSingh yes that is correct (because there are conflicts in VC2)

Comment: @Emma That's Weird, that worked for me perfectly in all my view controllers, as it automatically detects the textfield views & it automatically adjusts it.

Comment: @Emma Just to confirm have you added files of `IQKeyboardManagerSwift` in your code?

Comment: @Emma And you are following the set of requirements i.e.  Minimum iOS Target: iOS 8.0
Minimum Xcode Version: Xcode 6.3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79426/discussion-between-emma-and-rajat-deep-singh).

Answer (score 0):

You may get help from TPKeyboardAvoiding sample to solve this issue. Please have a look here https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding

Comment: is there a swift version?

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there.

In your `keyboardWillShow:` method you need to set the `contentInset` and the `scrollIndicatorInsets`

Example:

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSDictionary *info = [notification userInfo];

    CGREct keyboardRect = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfo] CGRectValue];

    CGFloat bottomInset = keyboardRect.size.height;

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, bottomInset, 0.0);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        self.contentInset = contentInsets;
        self.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
    }];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I gave this a try, but my viewcontroller does not have `contentInset` and `scrollIndicatorInsets`. How should they be defined?

Comment: This would work on a `UIScrollView`. I have written the code above in a previous `UITableView` implementation.