# How to recognize gesture from custom view in VC

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview, uigesturerecognizer, gesture

I have tableVC, it contains from cells with customViews.
That customViews contains from 3 imageViews, so then I click on imageView, it makes some action. To achieve it I added UITapGestureRecognizers to imageView.

Now I need to be notified then this cells are tapped in my tableVC. I get this events in didSelectRowAtIndexPath, but only if I do not touch any of imageViews with gestures.

How can I receive tap notification in my tableVC about touching my cell completely ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12851794/1801544 ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192480/uitapgesturerecognizer-breaks-uitableview-didselectrowatindexpath

Comment: thanks, solved with 2 link

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get cell that is tapped - `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is way to go. If you want to get the tapped image inside that cell - implement delegate for that ( https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html ) and do the corresponding actions. I see that you mentioned `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, but I am not sure what was your problem.

Also I didn't put any code since I don't know if you are using swift or objective-c.