# Cancel gesturerecognizer when touching UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, keyboard, hide

I have a view with 2 tableview and several textfield, I have implemented an extension to hide the keyboard:

The keyboard hides when I touch the screen but I would like to disable UITapGestureRecognizer when I touch the TableView, otherwise I can not interact with the cells.

```
extension UIViewController {

func OcultarTecladoTocarPantalla() {
    let tap : UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIViewController.OcultarTeclado))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}
@objc func OcultarTeclado() {
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

}

Comment: Where have you added your UITapGestureRecognizer? To your viewcontroller or tableview?

Comment: I've added it to the viewcontroller

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I see that you are extending UIViewController (which may not be advisable because it applies to **all** instances and subclasses of UIViewController), but you should still be able to set up the delegate. Make the following changes (code is pulled from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33276728/5491325)).

Extend `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` by writing `extension UIViewController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {`

Set the delegate when you add the gesture recognizer:
`tap.delegate = self`

Implement the following delegate method. It will need to be modified slightly to handle two tableviews.

```
// UIGestureRecognizerDelegate method
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    if touch.view?.isDescendantOfView(self.tableView) == true {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

---

Previous answer:

If the `cancelsTouchesInView` property of `UIGestureRecognizer` is false the view underneath it will receive touches in addition to the gesture recognizer.

If you do want to effectively disable the gesture for that case, implement the delegate method `gestureRecognizer(_:shouldReceive:)` and return false if the touch is in the tableview.

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizerdelegate/1624214-gesturerecognizer.

Comment: As I implement the gestureRecognizer (_: shouldReceive :) method to cancel the touches if the TableView is touched, I can not find the way

Comment: Are you having issues with setting up the delegate or determining if the touch is in the tableview? I found the answer to the second on what looks like an almost identical question to yours here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192480/uitapgesturerecognizer-breaks-uitableview-didselectrowatindexpath.

Answer (score -1):

For Swift 5: (Don't forget to set delegate of your tap gesture instance)

```
extension MyViewController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate{
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
        if touch.view?.isDescendant(of: self.mTableView) == true {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
}
```